# How to create a menu super voice in WP?

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I am pretty new in WP (I came from Joomla) and I am finding some difficulties to do the following operation in WP Main Menu.

If you go on this site you can easy understand what I need: http://www.saranistri.com/saranistriWPnew/

As you can see in this website there is to much main menu voices (and the Main Menu takes up too much space) so I want group some voices as sub voices into a main voices.

I want something like this Joomla Main Menu: http://lnx.erusma.org/en/ in which, for example, if you pass the mouse on the Who We Are voice you can say the subvoice. Can I do the same thing in WP? (I do not want to associate the main voice to a specific page to a category, this simply must be not clickable)

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Just go to the menu editor and drag an item under another parent item.

Comment: If you want this item have no link, just create a custom link item, using '#' for url.